# How to upload image into the cell of spreadsheet using PHPSpreadSheet?

Tags: phpspreadsheet

I'm working on a project for my customer who requested an ability to generate Excel spreadsheets containing images. Not links to the images, but full-sized images implemented directly in the spreadsheet.

Is PHPSpreadSheet capable of doing this? I have read the documentation, but the closest match I found is https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-a-drawing-to-a-worksheet - though  I'm not sure if in such case drawing = image.

Answer (score 0):

In excel you can't put an image in a cell but what you can do is place above a cell. Just how phpSpreadSheet do. They give Coordinates to the image so i knows where to be placed

```
    $drawing = new Drawing();
    $drawing->setName('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
    $drawing->setDescription('PhpSpreadsheet logo');
    $drawing->setPath('image.jpg'); // path to your image
    $drawing->setHeight(36);
    $drawing->setCoordinates('A1'); //Coordinates to where it should go or be placed at
//        $drawing->setOffsetX(30);
    $drawing->setWidth(200);
    $drawing->setHeight(80);
    $drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
```